# Get-AzureRmVM requires a name parameter?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-cloud-shell

If I run this powershell command from an Azure cloud shell it executes fine and gives me a list of all VMs in the specified resource group:

> Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "MyGroup" -Status

If I execute it in a runbook from an automation account I get an error;

> Get-AzureRmVM : Cannot process command because of one or more missing
>   mandatory parameters: Name. At TestAutomationAccount-Job-StartVM:20 char:20
>   + 
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzureRmVM], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingMandatoryParameter,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.GetAzureVMCommand

I'm trying to get a list of VMs within a resource group, and can't figure out why the apparent difference of behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to reproduce the same exception for the `Get-AzureRmVM` cmdlet when running in the Azure Automation runbook.

The root cause to this issue is simply due to the **version mismatch** of the `Get-AzureRmVM` cmdlet in the Azure Automation environment and Azure Cloud Shell (PowerShell) environment.

The `Get-AzureRmVM` cmdlet is under the **AzureRm.Compute** PowerShell module.

When I use the below cmdlet to get the version of **AzureRm.Compute** in the Azure Automation environment.

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name AzureRm.Compute -Refresh
```

The version I get is **1.2.1** for the Azure Automation environment as shown below.

[image]

When I use the below cmdlet to get the version of **AzureRm.Compute** in the Azure Cloud Shell (PowerShell) session.

```
Get-AzureRmCommand Get-AzureRmVM
```

The version I get is **3.4.1** for the Azure Cloud Shell (PowerShell) environment as shown below.

[image]

Hence I believe the **AzureRm.Compute** module version mismatch in these 2 environments explained the different behavior and parameters expectation for the `Get-AzureRmVM` cmdlet.

Hope this helps.

**Addendum:**
If you want to get the same experience for the `Get-AzureRmVM` cmdlet as it is in the Azure Cloud Shell environment, you can go to the Modules section in your Azure Automation account, select the AzureRm.Compute module and update it to the version to be the same as the Azure Cloud Shell environment.

[image]

Comment: Great explanation, thank you!  Now to figure out why my "Update Azure Modules" option is greyed out.  Maybe a permissions issue?

Comment: Was able to update by importing from the Module Gallery.  Thanks!